# TP-Link TL-WN723N Has Very Weak Signal

Tags: networking

I just reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04 to resolve some minor issues. Before my network adapter worked flawlessly.

Now after I reinstalled 14.04 the adapter picks up that there are networks, but has usually 0 bars on them. How can I fix this?

I don't know where to begin since last time I just plugged it in and it worked, and now the signal is horrible.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: This solution is working for me so far, but I have only used the internet for about an hour.

First off, I figured out that this issue was a problem with the drivers. Thus, I was prompted to start searching for drivers for my wireless adapter (formally called the mini wireless n usb adapter, which brought up more results regarding this error).

[I came across this website](https://community.linuxmint.com/hardware/view/5413) which had drivers for my particular adapter.

After following there instructions on how to install the driver, I rebooted and started using the internet. The only step I did differently was I just performed

```
sudo nautilus
```

Which made transferring the driver files to where they needed to be a bit more user friendly.